# Should mDNSResponder ever take 9%+ of my CPU?

Tags: macos, networking

Seems ridiculous, based on the process name, that it would be taking so much CPU.

I’m currently transferring a large file over the network. Is that why?

Comment: How many mDNS-capable machines are on your network?

Comment: err, no more than 3 or 4, assuming all OS X and iPhone/iPad devices are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing large file transfers, then you are possibly saturating some part of the i/o subsystems.

When something is listed as using CPU, it can be due to i/o wait rather than actual processing - the cpu must wait for an i/o operation to complete before it can move on.

You can confirm this by looking at the i/o wait levels:

```
$ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  2      0 383592  56924 2345356    0    0    93   137    4   11  0  1 74 20
```

The last figure shows that 20% of the cpu is consumed waiting for i/o.

mDNSresolver may simply have been trying to write to disk or request memory (that needed a page swap) and the cpu had to wait a while before it completed.

Comment: `-bash: vmstat: command not found`

Comment: @DanielBeck Yeah, I wasn't meaning the vmstat command specifically, but whatever command is available that allows the OP to see io wait levels.

Comment: If you find anything that provides this information, let me know. Haven't been able to find anything...

Comment: @DanielBeck do you have access to OSX?  If so, `top` should show current iowait.  I can reflect this in the answer if so.  Or is `vm_stat` still there?

Comment: OS X Lion. `top` has columns `PID COMMAND %CPU TIME #TH #WQ #PORTS #MREGS RPRVT RSHRD RSIZE VPRVT VSIZE PGRP PPID STATE UID FAULTS COW MSGSENT MSGRECV SYSBSD SYSMACH CSW PAGEINS KPRVT KSHRD USER`, shows only `CPU usage: 11.8% user, 12.26% sys, 76.65% idle` in the header, and the man page doesn't state anything related to I/O wait AFAICT; `vm_stat` really only shows virtual memory data (page counts for free, inactive etc., pageins, pageouts, and "translation faults").